# SSE lost its connection and auto-reconnect periodically

Tags: html, server-sent-events

I'm trying to view the data changes logged in my server in the browser using SSE, so i did:

**demo_sse.php :**

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

$ini_array = parse_ini_file("online.ini", true);
$data2 = json_encode($ini_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

echo "retry: 5000\n\n";
echo "data: {$data2}\n\n";

ob_end_flush();
flush();
```

**index.html**

```
<script>

    var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");

    source.onopen = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log('onopen', source.readyState);
    }

    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
        console.log('onmessage', source.readyState);
    };

    source.onerror = (err) => {
        console.log('onerror', source.readyState);
        console.error('Error occurred:', err);
    };
</script>
```

when i check the console, I get this every 5 sec:

```
onopen 1
onmessage 1
onerror 0
```

data is received with no fault but the connection is lost and reconnected every 5 sec as I defined and before that, it was every 3 sec.

any idea why the connection drops and reconnect again and again?

[image]

Comment: Your browser says you request "svg.php" but in your scripts php & js you write "demo_sse.php". In your php file, you just parse the ini file and encode is as json, send it to the client and then dont do anything. Its possible that the php script/interpreter terminates the http connection to the client because there is nothing that keeps the php process up, like a loop or async stuff which can emit more events. What do you want to achive with your SSE? There is nothing that "... data changes ..."